# Could an S3 filename and bucket be a security risk if public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Someone has bought this up internally and I do not know how to answer.

I am using a lambda function to copy an uploaded file from one private s3 bucket to another (also private), and then send a webhook message to Slack to say it has been done.

The webhook message includes the filename and the bucket names.

Although this is within Slack, and therefore 'secure' anyway, if we assume that the Slack account was accessed and the filename/bucket names seen, could they be used in anyway to get access to them or even assist an attacker?

I cannot think of anything except potentially giving the attacker some sort of idea of what it contains and what to look for.

Comment: If the buckets are private even if someone sees the bucket and object names they wouldn't be able to access them. But in the question it says "if public" so to be on the same page are they private or public?

Comment: I meant if the filename and bucket name were to be made public (i.e. shared in a public way like twitter or something), not the s3 bucket itself being 'public' (they are private). Urgh. You answered the question right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filename doesn't do you any good if you don't have access to the bucket to get to the file. *Unless of course your filename is: **my-password-for-netflix-is-opensesame.txt***

I do have some clients that are so protective that they *might* even consider the possibility of someone finding out the file name against their security policy, but that would really depend on the client I guess. Personally, I don't see any issue.

On the other hand, I tend to use very generic names for most files, e.g. GUIDs, when I store them on S3, so its usually a moot point for me.